# Toolbar SearchView is not focusable

Tags: android

Im attempting to implement a search button in a `Toolbar` that will expand into a `SearchView`. To do this, I first added a search button to the menu using this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title=""
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />

</menu>
```

I then add a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and add a callback for when the `SearchView` is focused, using this code in `onCreateView`:

```
binding.libraryToolbar.menu.apply {
    val searchView = findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this@LibraryFragment)
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        this.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_sorting, !hasFocus)
    }
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the `SearchView` will not focus whatsoever. When I click on it, it seems to be flicker for a split-second before going back to being inactive, with the soft keyboard not showing up at all. The callback I added does not seem to be called as well when the SearchView is selected. I've attached an example of what the problem looks like below:

[image: The strange flickering behavior]

I havent really tried anything as I really dont know why this is happening. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Does it work if you remove your listeners? What causes it to stop working (i.e., if you only added one of the listeners, does that work? What about if you only add the other listener)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It still doesnt work if I remove any combination of the listeners. If I reduce the fragment's startup code to just the menu setup the same problem occurs. Could it be because Im using a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I actually found a "Solution" to this problem, I still dont know why the problem was happening but it works.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some experimenting, I found that by setting `isIconified` to false when the search button is clicked, the `SearchView` will become focus-able.

```
binding.libraryToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    if (it.itemId == R.id.action_search) {
        (it.actionView as SearchView).isIconified = false
    }
}
```